# How do I create an NSubstitute Sitecore item?

Tags: unit-testing

Is it possible to create a mock Sitecore (using Sitecore 8.2) item using NSubstitute? I would like to write a unit test to cover the following pipeline processor code, which adds a child folder item called "Items" if it does not exist.

```
public void Process(GetRenderingDatasourceArgs args)
{
  var renderingItem = args.RenderingItem;

  if (!renderingItem.GetChildren().Any(item => item.Name == "Items" && item.TemplateID == TemplateIDs.Folder))
    renderingItem.Add("Items", new TemplateID(TemplateIDs.Folder));
}
```

I would like to write unit tests that cover the following scenarios:

- When the passed in item does not have a child "Items" folder then one is created. The substitute item should return a child item of the correct type, and should be able to verify that the `Add` method was not called.
- When it does have a child "Items" folder another one is not created. The substitute item should not return any children, and should confirm that the `Add` method was called with the correct parameters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is possible with Sitecore 8.2, since the `GetChildren` and `Add` methods became virtual with this version.  (You *could* create an NSubstitute Sitecore 8.1 item, but NSubstiute would not be able to interact with its methods, so there would not be any point in doing so.)

To create a Subsitute item, you need to:

1. Create an item ID:

   ```
   var itemId = ID.NewID;
   ```
2. Create an item definition:

   ```
   var definition = new ItemDefinition(itemId, string.Empty, ID.Null, ID.Null);
   ```
3. Create an item data object:

   ```
   var data = new ItemData(
     definition, 
     Language.Current, 
     Sitecore.Data.Version.First, 
     new FieldList());
   ```
4. Create a substitute database, which is easy in Sitecore 8.2 because the class is now abstract:

   ```
   Database db = Substitute.For<Database>();
   ```
5. Create the substitute item, passing in the itemID, ItemData object, and substitute database as parameters:

   ```
   Item item = Substitute.For<Item>(itemId, data, db);
   ```
6. If the code under test interacts with the Paths property, you will need to set this:

   `item.Paths.Returns(Substitute.For<ItemPath>(item));`

Now that you have a Substitute item, you can use the `Returns` and `Received` methods as normal with NSubstitute:

```
public class ProcessorTests
{
    [Fact]
    public void Processor_ItemsFolderMissing_CreatesIt()
    {
        var sut = new DataSourceFolderCreator();
        Item renderingItem = MakeSubstituteItem();
        renderingItem.SetChildren(new ItemList());
        renderingItem.Database.Should().NotBeNull();

        var args = new GetRenderingDatasourceArgs(renderingItem, renderingItem.Database);

        sut.Process(args);

        renderingItem.Received()
          .Add("Items", new TemplateID(TemplateIDs.Folder));
    }

    [Fact]
    public void Processor_ItemsFolderPresent_DoesNotCreateIt()
    {
        var sut = new DataSourceFolderCreator();
        var folderItem = MakeSubstituteItem();
        var renderingItem = MakeSubstituteItem();
        folderItem.Name.Returns("Items");
        folderItem.TemplateID.Returns(TemplateIDs.Folder);
        renderingItem.SetChildren(new ItemList { folderItem });
        var args = new GetRenderingDatasourceArgs(renderingItem, renderingItem.Database);

        sut.Process(args);

        renderingItem.DidNotReceiveWithAnyArgs().Add("", new TemplateID());
    }

    private Item MakeSubstituteItem()
    {
        var itemId = ID.NewID;
        var definition = new ItemDefinition(
          itemId, string.Empty, ID.Null, ID.Null);
        var data = new ItemData(
          definition, Language.Current,
          Sitecore.Data.Version.First, new FieldList());
        var db = Substitute.For<Database>();

        var item =  Substitute.For<Item>(itemId, data, db);
        item.Paths.Returns(Substitute.For<ItemPath>(item));

        return item;
    }
}

public static class ItemExtensions
{
    public static void SetChildren(this Item item, ItemList items = null)
    {
        if (items == null)
        {
            items = new ItemList();
        }
        item.GetChildren().Returns(new ChildList(item, items));
    }
}
```

Comment: I keep coming back to this answer! :p Thanks.

Comment: I have a NuGet package that does this too. https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoSitecore/ :)

Answer (score 10):

**Mocking Pipeline Code in Sitecore before 8.2**

If you are working in Sitecore before 8.2 your best bet would be to look into using **Sitecore FakeDB**; it offers an in-memory representation of Sitecore.

It allows tests for all parts of Sitecore including pipeline code.

An example from the documentation is:

```
[Fact]
public void HowToUnitTestAdvancedPipelineCallWithMockedProcessor()
{
  var args = new Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs();

  using (Sitecore.FakeDb.Db db = new Sitecore.FakeDb.Db())
  {
    // register a processor mock in the Pipeline Watcher
    var processor =
      Substitute.For<Sitecore.FakeDb.Pipelines.IPipelineProcessor>();

    processor
      .When(p => p.Process(args))
      .Do(ci => ci.Arg<Sitecore.Pipelines.PipelineArgs>()
                  .CustomData["Result"] = "Ok");

    db.PipelineWatcher.Register("mypipeline", processor);

    // call the pipeline
    Sitecore.Pipelines.CorePipeline.Run("mypipeline", args);

    // check the result is set
    Assert.Equal("Ok", args.CustomData["Result"]);
  }
}
```

It also allows mocking for:

- Authentication
- Authorization
- Role
- Roles-In-Roles
- Membership

**References**

- https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/Sitecore_FakeDb.aspx
- https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb
- https://github.com/sergeyshushlyapin/Sitecore.FakeDb/wiki/Pipelines